# Generating random networks of a specific area in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network, random

I want to compare the richness of mammals between an implemented biological corridor that connects two patches of forest, against a random generated network connecting these same patches. For this purpose **I want to generate a random network of corridors that would connect my two forest patches of interest and but that also has the same area as my "real" biological corridor** (that is the one that has been implemented already).

Has someone done this type of analysis in the past and can guide me through on how to do it? Any information on what tools or procedures I could use to generate this type of data will be useful. I am not a spatial analyst expert so I am looking for the easiest way to do this. I have almost all extensions for ArcGIS 10.3.1. except the Network analysist tools.

Comment: Have you tried searching keyword random walk? From there you can try to find arcgis implementations. I do not think your question require Network Analyst but you would like to have a look at the Distance toolset in Spatial Analyst toolbox (Spatial Analyst Tools.tbx>Distance). Also, a snapshot of your problem will help people to better understand the content. It is a bit unclear what you mean by random (it may not be purely random) network, how you define width/length constraints, etc.